# How the yield statement of __iter__ works in TreeNode object (BST)

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, binary-search-tree

I'm implementing a simple binary sort tree in python; the code below is a snippet.

I've read about the `__iter__` implemention of TreeNode somewhere, and I try to understand how it works. The code works fine, but I was wondering about one thing:

How does the **yield** statements actually works here? It seems it starts with the root, traversing the left tree first, print each element but still starts from the root every time.

```
class BinaryST(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self.size

    def __iter__(self):

        class EmptyIter():
            def next(self):
                raise StopIteration

        if self.root:
            return self.root.__iter__()
        return EmptyIter()

class TreeNode(object):

    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

        def __iter__(self):
        # visit the left tree
        if self.has_left_child():
            for child in self.left:
                print 'yielding left child'
                yield child

        # back to current element; root
        print 'yielding root ele'
        yield self.val

       if self.has_right_child():
           for child in self.right:
               print 'yield right child'
               yield child
```

---

Output:

```
bt = bst.BST()
bt.insert(5)
bt.insert(7)
bt.insert(3)
bt.insert(1)
for i in bt:
    print i

yielding root ele
yielding left child
yielding left child
1
yielding root ele
yielding left child
3
yielding root ele
5
yielding root ele
yield right child
7
```

I'm trying to understand the code flow here. How does the stack looks? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could add `print` statement at the beginning of `__iter__` and before every `yield` to get a better understanding on what's happening and which order.

Comment: @niemmi thanks for the direction, I added the output but it still unclear to me. It looks like for every element I traverse the whole tree starting from the root. Then when I get to the child I need to print it just prints it and starts over from the root

Comment: You could alter your print statements to output `self.val` so you would know at which node the execution happens.